How do I label dots in scatter by selected names from the data
I want to label only custom selected dots, "which is randomly taken without any specific criteria", in scatter plot.
I tried:
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) +
geom_text(label=rownames(mtcars))


But I want to label only following names:
Merc 450SE
Cadillac Fleetwood
Lincoln Continental
Chrysler Imperial
Fiat 128
Honda Civic
Toyota Corolla
Fiat X1-9
Porsche 914-2
Lotus Europa

The expected output will be:

This question is not a duplicate of the above mentioned question. In the given link they discuss about labelling using conditions. But here I am asking about labelling them about any randomly selected names.

This question is not a duplicate of the above mentioned question. In the given link they discuss about labelling using conditions. But here I am asking about labelling them about any randomly selected names.

This question is not a duplicate of the above mentioned question. In the given link they discuss about labelling using conditions. But here I am asking about labelling them about any randomly selected names.

You can subset the data when using geom_text. And to circumvent the overlap issue, you can use geom_text_repel from the ggrepel package:
library(ggrepel)

show.names <- c('Merc 450SE',
                'Cadillac Fleetwood',
                'Lincoln Continental',
                'Chrysler Imperial',
                'Fiat 128',
                'Honda Civic',
                'Toyota Corolla',
                'Fiat X1-9',
                'Porsche 914-2',
                'Lotus Europa')

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text_repel(data=mtcars[rownames(mtcars) %in% show.names,], 
            label=show.names)


