How to get GGPLOT to not error when doing selective labelling?
I was trying to do a scatter plot of a table, while only labeling 2 specific points. The table looks something like this
"Country","Continent","GDP","HCI"
Afghanistan,Asia,1991,0.40
Albania,Europe,19566,0.63
Algeria,Africa,13682,0.53
Angola,Africa,7077,0.36
Antigua and Barbuda,Americas,25449,0.60
Argentina,Americas,26506,0.60
...

With the following code:
ctry_inf <- read.csv("Paises_PIB_ICH.csv")


ctry_inf_selec <- ctry_inf[ctry_inf$Continent == "Asia" | ctry_inf$Continent == "Africa",  ]



ggplot(ctry_inf_selec, aes(x=GDP, y=HCI)) + geom_point() + 
  scale_x_continuous(trans='log10') + 
  geom_text(aes(label = 
                  ifelse(ctry_inf$Country == "Namibia" | ctry_inf$Country == "United Arab Emirates", 
                         as.character(Country), "")))

I get this error:
> ggplot(ctry_inf_selec, aes(x=GDP, y=HCI)) + geom_point() + 
+   scale_x_continuous(trans='log10') + 
+   geom_text(aes(label = ifelse(ctry_inf$Continent == "Asia", as.character(Country), "")))
Error in `geom_text()`:
! Problem while computing aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 2nd layer.
Caused by error in `check_aesthetics()`:
! Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (91)
✖ Fix the following mappings: `label`
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

error encountered
How do I make it work? I cannot use any other extra libraries other than ggplot2.
I tried several ways to do labeling and all of them result in errors.

Just use ifelse(Country == etc. There is no need for the data set name. Or, like in the question's 2nd example, ifelse(Continent == etc.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15015356/how-to-do-selective-labeling-with-ggplot-geom-point and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78554391/how-do-i-label-dots-in-scatter-by-selected-names-from-the-data/78554415#78554415

You don't need the data.frame name in aes(). ggplot2 uses non standard evaluation to get the columns from the data and to explicitly extract the columns is a frequent source for errors.
library(ggplot2)

ctry_inf <- read.csv(text = '"Country","Continent","GDP","HCI"
Afghanistan,Asia,1991,0.40
Albania,Europe,19566,0.63
Algeria,Africa,13682,0.53
Angola,Africa,7077,0.36
Antigua and Barbuda,Americas,25449,0.60
Argentina,Americas,26506,0.60')

ctry_inf_selec <- ctry_inf[ctry_inf$Continent == "Asia" | ctry_inf$Continent == "Africa",  ]

ggplot(ctry_inf_selec, aes(x=GDP, y=HCI)) + geom_point() + 
  scale_x_continuous(trans='log10') + 
  geom_text(aes(label = ifelse(Country == "Algeria" | Country == "Angola", Country, "")),
            vjust = -1) +
  ylim(0.35, 0.55)


Created on 2024-06-05 with reprex v2.1.0
You can simplify the code above by creating a vector of countries to be labelled and then use %in% to select them with ifelse.
countries <- c("Angola", "Algeria")

ggplot(ctry_inf_selec, aes(x=GDP, y=HCI)) + geom_point() + 
  scale_x_continuous(trans='log10') + 
  geom_text(aes(label = ifelse(Country %in% countries, Country, "")),
            vjust = -1) +
  ylim(0.35, 0.55)


Created on 2024-06-05 with reprex v2.1.0

One major problem - you're trying to plot ctry_inf_selec, which should have fewer rows than ctry_inf, (given that you're filtering it) which means that the vector you're passing to aes(label = ..., given that it is based on ctry_inf, has more entries than there are rows in the data set you're trying to plot. The solution to this is to base your ifelse(...) that generates the point labels off of ctry_inf_selec.

Your answer would be more useful to others with the addition of a working code example. See how to write a good answer for more details.
